# ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file 'RemObjectsSDK.framework/RemObjectsSDK' for architecture i386

Tags: xcode6, remobjects, ios8.1, dataabstract

i'm new on iOS Development and I Recently updated to **OS X Yosemite** and **Xcode 6**, so i tried to update my Apps to **iOS 8.1**

The thing is that i had a project running on **iOS 7.1** and it was made on **Xcode 5.1** and **OS X 10.8.5** with **RemObjects Data Abstract for Xcode - 7.0.63.1055**

I updated the App to run in **iOS 8.1** and when I try to compile my project it appears the following error:

```
Ld /Users/ingenieria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IC4-bjbysgznhpelujdvlqbfkmfrckyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IC4.app/IC4 normal i386
cd /Users/ingenieria/Desktop/04/OMEGA/iSIREPolProyect
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/Users/ingenieria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IC4-bjbysgznhpelujdvlqbfkmfrckyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Developer/RemObjects\ Software/Bin/iOS/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ingenieria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IC4-bjbysgznhpelujdvlqbfkmfrckyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/ingenieria/Desktop/04/OMEGA/iSIREPolProyect -F/Developer/RemObjects\ Software/Bin/Debug -filelist /Users/ingenieria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IC4-bjbysgznhpelujdvlqbfkmfrckyx/Build/Intermediates/IC4.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IC4.build/Objects-normal/i386/IC4.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/ingenieria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IC4-bjbysgznhpelujdvlqbfkmfrckyx/Build/Intermediates/IC4.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IC4.build/IC4.app.xcent -framework DataAbstract -framework RemObjectsSDK -framework MessageUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework Social -framework Parse -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreAudio -framework CFNetwork -framework AVFoundation -framework ShinobiGrids -framework AudioToolbox -framework AdSupport -framework Accounts -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lz.1.1.3 -lz.1.2.5 -lz.1 -lz -lsqlite3.0 -lsqlite3 -liconv.2.4.0 -liconv.2 -liconv -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ingenieria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IC4-bjbysgznhpelujdvlqbfkmfrckyx/Build/Intermediates/IC4.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/IC4.build/Objects-normal/i386/IC4_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ingenieria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IC4-bjbysgznhpelujdvlqbfkmfrckyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IC4.app/IC4

ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Developer/RemObjects Software/Bin/Debug/RemObjectsSDK.framework/RemObjectsSDK' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I’ve already tried this with **RemObjects Data Abstract for Cocoa - 8.1.85.1143 - Trial** and the error stills the same, what do you thing i could do?

**ps: It all happened after I updated the code because of deprecated code.**

Edit: i have already Cleaned and builded the Project many times and the error still appears

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to link against /Developer/RemObjects Software/Bin/Debug/RemObjectsSDK.framework (whatever that is) when building your project.  Your project is an iOS Simulator app and that framework is an OS X framework.  You cannot use OS X binaries in iOS Simulator apps as they are not compatible.

On older versions of iOS, you would encounter runtime errors (incorrect values or crashes).  On iOS 8.0, this became a link-time error.

You need to build a version of RemObjectsSDK.framework for the iOS Simulator.

Comment: Thanks for that @Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia and after making some research i found out something familiar, so i keep looking on RemObjects wiki and i found an article about how to link the framework for iOS - [Article](http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/WIP:How_to_link_Custom_Static_Libraries_from_your_Xcode_Projects) but now there is another problem...  __<DataAbstract/DataAbstract.h> file not found.__ 

i've Cleaned and Remade the process in the article above but the same error appears

Comment: You need to set FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS or HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS so that header can be found.

Comment: In __Framework Search Paths__ i have: $inherited, $(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR, $(PROJECT_DIR), /Developer/Parse and /Developer/FacebookSDK. For __Header Search Path__ i have "/Developer/RemObjects Software/Source". and for __Library Search Path__ i have "/Developer/RemObjects Software/Bin/iOS/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)" and still the same error.

Comment: I suspect you are having issues due to the space in the path.  Make sure it is quoted properly.  Also, is that file really present?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Jeremy it seems like i had to put the same path on __General Settings > Header Search Paths__ on both __Target__ and __Project__, i Cleaned the project and Build it and it worked... i guess it was a newbie mistake.